# Issue with setting up MSSQL with Jhipster

Tags: sql-server, maven-3, jhipster

Im trying to use jhipster for my backend project, one of the requirement is to use mssql. Based on my previous question :
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4612#issuecomment-265076842

@ruddel did advise me to use this

```
datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=msqltest
        username: SA
        password: yourStrong(!)Password
        hikari:
                  .........
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        database: SQL_SERVER
                  .........
```

after setting this i need to run maven command so Jhipster initial entities can be generated for gateway project and Microservice by liquibase with this command as per guide by jhipster

```
liquibase:diff
```

and encountered this error:

```
[INFO] Settings
----------------------------
[INFO]     driver: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
[INFO]     url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=IASDB
[INFO]     username: devuser
[INFO]     password: *****
[INFO]     use empty password: false
[INFO]     properties file: null
[INFO]     properties file will override? false
[INFO]     prompt on non-local database? true
[INFO]     clear checksums? false
[INFO]     changeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
[INFO]     context(s): null
[INFO]     label(s): null
[INFO]     referenceDriver: null
[INFO]     referenceUrl: hibernate:spring:com.mbb.ias.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.Spate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
[INFO]     referenceUsername: null
[INFO]     referencePassword: null
[INFO]     referenceDefaultSchema: null
[INFO]     diffChangeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20161208102850_changelog.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.109 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-08T18:28:54+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/342M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) on project ias-gateway: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseExceptionnot find database driver: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver -> [Help 1]
```

so i refer back to jhipster they did mention to change the setting inside pom.xml also  which i did as per :

```
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
            <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
            <driver>com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig</driver>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=IASDB</url>
            <defaultSchemaName>IASDB</defaultSchemaName>
            <username>devuser</username>
            <password>CIATopSecret</password>
            <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.mbb.ias.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <logging>debug</logging>
        </configuration>
```

it will hrow the error as per above msg or this :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) on project ias-gateway: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseExceptionnot find database driver: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver -> [Help 1]
```

i did try to change my pom to use com.microsoft.SQLServerDriver, it throw me

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff (default-cli) on project ias-gateway: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseExceptionnot find database driver: com.microsoft.SQLServerDriver -> [Help 1]
```

Anyone to advise how to change my pom? if i want to use sub generator, i need to generate the entities one by one? sorry for the noob question. here is my Jhipster info:

````
##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**

```yaml
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.0",
    "baseName": "IASGateway",
    "packageName": "com.mbb.ias",
    "packageFolder": "com/mbb/ias",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": "kafka",
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "3f2b1ccd09c528361c2b0f321f96fb62728e9830",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```


##### **Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

ls: no such file or directory: .jhipster/*.json

##### **Browsers and Operating System**

java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

git version 2.10.2.windows.1

node: v7.2.1

npm: 3.10.10

bower: 1.8.0

gulp:
[18:56:33] CLI version 1.2.2
[18:56:33] Local version 3.9.1

yeoman: 1.8.5
````

Answer (score 2):

For full MSSQL support, you should use v3.12.1 - your project was generated with v3.12.0, before we supported that database.  You also shouldn't run `liquibase:diff` initially (it will fail until the app runs liquibase for the first time).

The following code is the pom configuration for  MSSQL liquibase from a freshly generated project, the main difference I see is the driver tag:

```
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <driver></driver>
                <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=databaseName</url>
                <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
                <username>SA</username>
                <password>yourStrong(!)Password</password>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.mycompany.myapp.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <logging>debug</logging>
            </configuration>
```